# how to remove a row OR a column in a matrix in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

So i have been searching for an answer to this for a while and i just found people using ArrayList and one person that did it but it was to remove both the row and column at the same time i think, im trying to do it by following the last one mentioned but i dont know what "continue;" means, how and when its used.. this is the code i found (i modified the name of the variables but its still kinda the same):

```
public static long [][] removecol(long mat[][],int ren, int col){
    int rengre=ren;//  row to remove
    int colre=col;// column to remove
    long mat2[][]= new long [mat.length-1][mat[0].length-1];
    int p=0;
    for( int i = 0; i <mat.length; ++i)
    {
        if ( i == rengre)
            continue;
        int q = 0;
        for( int j = 0; j <mat[0].length; ++j)
        {
            if ( j == colre)
                continue;

            mat2[p][q] = mat[i][j];
            ++q;
        }
        ++p;
    }
        return mat2;
}
```

I was thinking maybe separating in two methods, one to remove row and other to remove column, something like this:

```
public static long [][] removerow(long mat[][],int ren){
    int rengre=ren;//row to remove
    long mat2[][]= new long [mat.length-1][mat[0].length];
    int p=0;
    for( int i = 0; i <mat.length; ++i)
    {
        if ( i == rengre)
            continue;
        int q = 0;
        for( int j = 0; j <mat[0].length; ++j)
        {
            if ( j == colre)
                continue;

            mat2[p][q] = mat[i][j];
            ++q;
        }
        ++p;
    }
        return mat2;
}
```

but i dont really know how to separate this between column and row...I know you might me tired of questions about this topic but i simply cannot come up with a way to do it :c help.

Comment: continue means skipping the rest of loop, it starts the next iteration of the loop. If your code, while any row or column is matched to be removed, it is not added to final array. Then the final array is returned from the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When **continue** is encountered,rest of your code in the loop will be skipped and next iteration of loop will take place.
For Ex:

```
  int [] numbers = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
   for(int x : numbers ) {
     if( x == 30 ) {
        continue;           
       }
     System.out.print( x );     //when x=30,these will not run;
     System.out.print("\n");
  }
```

Here,when x=30,the **continue** will be executed and your loop will go to next iteration instead of running your rest of the code.For more understanding on continue,look at [these examples.](http://www.java-examples.com/continue-statement)

Now,about your column/row removing problem.Your outer loop is used to remove row and inner loop is used to remove column.If you don't want to remove your column,then dont use **continue** in inner loop.Your code will be something like this...

```
 public static long [][] removerow(long mat[][],int ren){
    int rengre=ren;//row to remove
    long mat2[][]= new long [mat.length-1][mat[0].length];
    int p=0;
    for( int i = 0; i <mat.length; ++i)
    {
        if ( i == rengre)
            continue;
        int q = 0;
        for( int j = 0; j <mat[0].length; ++j)
        {
            mat2[p][q] = mat[i][j];
            ++q;
        }
        ++p;
    }
        return mat2;
}
```

Comment: oooh Thanks, and if i dont want to remove the row i change the continue section to the inner loop?

Comment: well..yes..but still try it by yourself and see